Can someone explain why ancillary statistic is needed in "orthodox statistics"?
I am reading Jaynes' Probability Theory: the Logic of Science.  In Chapter 8 Jaynes discusses the issue of ancillary statistic in "orthodox" setting, where he says that ancillary statistic is needed for following reason:

I am a bit confused about his statement.  He says "one is obliged to conclude that all estimates from a given estimator have the same accuracy, regardless of the configuration of the sample.".  Why is this the case?  If two datasets have the same mean but different variances, would it be natural to assume the estimator would give different estimates for "accuracy"?

The question in this post is different than the question in the topic of the post. That makes it a little hard to answer. I suggest editing the post for clarity.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

For instance, the sample size $n$ is usually ancillary and thus not contributing to the estimation of a parameter. But it is useful for assessing the error in estimating this parameter.


Yet if we hold that the accuracy of an estimate is determined by
the width of the sampling distribution for the estimator, one is obliged to conclude that all
estimates from a given estimator have the same accuracy, regardless of the configuration of the sample

This would suppose the sampling distribution is uniquely defined. Many (including Fisher) would disagree, there are some choices involved. Some of the hypothetical samples obtained in the frequency, repeated sampling setup might be very different from the actual sample, and not very relevant. This leads to ideas of relevant subsets, see for instance Is the sampling distribution of a complete sufficient statistic free from relevant subsets?
Bayesians like Jaynes does not have this particular relevance problem, as they condition on the actual sample $x$. Instead they need to convince themselves and others about the relevance of the prior ...
Ancillary statistics can be seen as a way of choosing such a relevant subset, for conditioning (also other uses). This is really explained shortly after your citation from Jaynes' book. But let us go to RA Fisher's last book,     "Statistical Methods and Scientific Inference" (Edinburgh: Oliver & Boyd. 1956.):

The most important step which has been taken so
far to complete the structure of the theory of estimation is the recognition of Ancillary statistics. The
notion was first developed in a detailed study of the
amount of information lost calculated exactly for a
number of trivial but representative problems. It
was shown not only that loss of information must
vanish if all types of sample yielding the same
estimate had identical Likelihood functions,

That is, if all possible samples giving the same estimate $\hat{\theta}(x)$, also have identical likelihood functions, then the usual (unconditional) sampling distribution is relevant (says Fisher). Otherwise, he uses ancillary statistics to choose possible, hypothetical, samples with similar likelihood functions as the actual sample. Ideally, the likelihood functions should all be identical, but that might not be possible by conditioning on a scalar function. So, there are problems with this approach, ancillaries might not exist, there might be more than one, so how to choose ... for a review see ANCILLARY STATISTICS: A REVIEW by M. Ghosh, N. Reid and D. A. S. Fraser.
One well-known example is Fisher's exact  test for the $2\times 2$ contingency table. The row and column margins are treated as ancillaries, so conditioned upon. In fact they are only approximately ancillary, surprisingly there is some small amount of information about the odds ratio in the margins!
